# How to export powershell code to csv correct column

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to export the result to CSV. Can someone guide me on how to do it

```
$Inventory = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\tdadmin\Desktop\hostname.txt'
foreach ($computer in $Inventory) {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Properties * | FT Name, LastLogonDate -Autosize
}
```

Comment: [Export-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1) ... read the help including the examples please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `Format-*` cmdlets unless you want to present data directly to a user. For selecting particular properties of your input objects use `Select-Object`. Use a pipeline and remove the loop (`Get-ADComputer` accepts pipeline input). Use `Export-Csv` for actually exporting the data to a CSV.

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\tdadmin\Desktop\hostname.txt' |
    Get-ADComputer -Properties * |
    Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv -NoType
```